# Building and running Monodevelop solution in OS X Terminal

Tags: c#, macos, command-line, terminal, monodevelop

I'd like to build and run a Monodevelop solution from the OS X Terminal. **What are the appropriate tools/commands to do this?**

I tried running `mdtools build` from the directory containing `MySolution.sln`. This results in `-bash: mdtools: command not found`. Where can I download and install `mdtools`? (if this is the right way to go).

I built the solution from the IDE. Then I tried to run it from `bin/Debug` with `mySolution.exe`. This resulted in the error message `-bash: mySolution.exe: command not found` (even though `ls` shows it exists).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a Mac, `mdtool` is not in the PATH, but can be found inside the MD app bundle, for example

```
/Applications/MonoDevelop.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool build MySolution.sln
```

Alternatively you could try `xbuild`, which is installed as part of Mono, and is in PATH. This is an implementation of MSBuild. Unfortunately it can't yet handle all the custom project types that `mdtool` can handle.

```
xbuild MySolution.sln
```

Comment: The command looks simple enough, but it seems to silently fail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143410/how-to-build-monotouch-project-using-mdtool

Comment: For anyone looking for *mdtool* in Xamarin Studio the path is "/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool"

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays if you run `xbuild` you also will get:

> ">>> xbuild tool is deprecated and will be removed in future updates, use msbuild instead <<<<"

So, you should go for:

```
msbuild Solution.sln
```

Answer (score -2):

See http://monodevelop.com/Developers/Mac_Support/Building_MonoDevelop_on_OS_X

Comment: This is about building a MD solution, not MD itself.